# Can(could) vs to be able to

Tags: modal-verbs

> My grandfather could speak five languages
>
> My grandfather was able to speak five languages.

What is the exact difference, as I know can/ could are used for abilities.

Comment: No significant difference.

Answer (score 3):

For general ability in the past, you use *could*. If the occassion happened once, you use *was/were able*.

It all depends on context if the action is considered  general ability. For punctual past abilities, which happened once, it's often used *was/were able to.*

> *I called him but I wasn't able to speak.* (*...  <s>I couldn't speak.</s>*)
>   (It was one time.)

Comment: This is a thought-provoking answer!  I'm not 100% sure I agree: consider "I climbed Mount Everest once, but I wasn't able to get to the top" versus "...but I couldn't get to the top."  Both of them sound acceptable to me.  And yet you're right that there is a bit of a difference in how we use them.  "My grandfather could lift a pony over his head" sounds a little different from "My grandfather was able to lift a pony over his head", like you say.

Comment: @stangdon I think the same. The difference is not always clear-cut. I think it probably focuses on how is considered the ability to be general or not.

Comment: @stangdon, I think that the rules may be different for negatives (no surprises there) but for an affirmative version of your sentence, Ustanak's Law works: "I climbed Mount Everest once, and I **was able to** get to the top" is fine because it's once, but I climbed Mount Everest once, and I **could** get to the top" is wrong.